# how to implement bar graph in wp8?

Tags: graph, windows-phone-8, bar-chart

I am new in wp8.

I want to implement bar graph in wp8 like in below image

[image]

How can i do this? I dont know how to start to implement bar graph in wp8.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a 3rd party control provider.

Microsoft, in their Dev Center app, uses the [Telerik Windows Phone charting controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx), but be mindful, these controls aren't free.

Comment: :thanks for giving answer but how to use this control and implement bar chart

Comment: @MansinhDodiya You'll have to work that out from their documentation. StackOverflow is not for getting others to do things for you. Read the documentation, look at samples and try implementing it. If you have specific issues with the code, as opposed to "it doesn't work/how do I use it?", then post another question and people are likely to help you.